# What make an image to be displayed only in IOS

Tags: android, react-native

As the title say

What make an image to be displayed only in IOS

in Android , it display a blank white image

the source fetched from a remote url

```
import { Image } from 'react-native';

image = {uri : "correct_image_url"}

<Image style={{width : 100 , zIndex : 999 , height : 100}} source={image} />
```

[image]

I use Expo , if this can help

Comment: Check as Platform in react-native. 
You can return a view instead of a image
or return uri in tag Image as an empty string if Platform=='android'

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Platform` from react-native to check if OS is ios or android

```
import { Image, Platform, View } from 'react-native';

image = {uri : "correct_image_url"}

{
  Platform.OS === 'ios' ? (
    <Image style={{width : 100 , zIndex : 999 , height : 100}} source={image} />
  ) : (<View style={{ backgroundColor: 'white', height: 100, width: 100 }} />)
}
```

Comment: I found the bug and added an answer to my question

Comment: Ok I misunderstood your question I thought you wanted to show image only on ios platform.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue (I miss-formulated the uri and typed it as url)

`looks {url : "image_source"}` works only in IOS

but `{uri : "image_source"}` works on both

this "i" was the bug which took many days with me